# When using DrivePicker get the webcontent link

Tags: google-app-maker

On a form I put a `DrivePicker` widget/button. This button opens my Google Drive and I can select an image. To show this image in an `Image` widget I need the webcontent link instead of the file URL link. The file URL link won't work.

By the property editor of the `DrivePicker` widget I put the following code at `onDocumentSelect` part.

```
varId = result.docs[0].id;
widget.datasource.item.strArtikelAfbeeldingId = result.docs[0].id;
widget.datasource.item.strArtikelAfbeeldingUrl = Drive.Files.get(varId).webContentLink;
```

Unfortunately I get no webcontentlink and got the following error message

> Drive is not defined
>   at pageTabelArtikelen.Form1.Form1Body.DrivePicker1.onDocumentSelect:3:50

How can I get a webcontentlink of a selected image when using `DrivePicker` widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a server function from the client to use Drive. So you can still run this function for the onDocumentSelect event, but you would want to declare a server function such as getFileWebContent() and then change your event code to:

Client

```
var Id = widget.selectedDocId;
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function() {
      //do something here with the returned link from server;
      })
      .withFailureHandler(function() {
      //optional failure handler;
      })
      .getFileWebContent(Id);
```

Server

```
function getFileWebContent(Id) {
  var link = Drive.Files.get(Id).WebContentLink;
  return link;
}
```

It would be more ideal to run the server code in the model onCreate event which is a server function. In this case your model can have a field for the file id and in your onCreate event you would run

```
var link = Drive.Files.get(record.FileId).webContentLink;
record.WebLink = link;
```

Comment: I put your last suggestion on an onSave event in a test app and that was working fine.  Unfortunately in my original app I still get the ReferenceError: 
 "Drive" is not defined. at models.tblArtikelen.onSaveEvent:1 - Modifying records: (Error) : "Drive" is not defined.
at models.tblArtikelen.onSaveEvent:1  Both putting the code on an event or adding script on the server gives the "Drive is not defined"  Any suggestions?

Comment: Findout why I got the "Drive is not defined error" I forgot in the app settings to add the Drive Api under Advanced Services